# How to implement following query

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server-2005

I have a table called for example `SomeTable` with columns `ID` `Line` `Machine` `Slot`.

Is it possible to make following query and how ?

I have a List of IDs to get as result table with results if values from my list located in the table.

If it in the table get some positive result if not some negative result.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Your description is not very clear. Can you post examples of data that is in the table and the expected output for each condition?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server 2005? There is a difference!

Comment: @Misnomer: I need it for both

Comment: I think he has an input list of IDs and he wants all rows from SomeTable that match one of those IDs plus a list of IDs that did not have a corresponding row in SomeTable.

Comment: Just out of curiosity why do you need it for both?

Comment: @Abe Miessler:the system I am working on should support both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `SQL Server`, you need to declare a table variable and fill it with your ids:

```
DECLARE  @myids TABLE (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT
INTO     @myids
VALUES   (1)

INSERT
INTO     @myids
VALUES   (2)

…

SELECT  CASE s.id WHEN t.id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM    @myids t
LEFT JOIN
        sometable s
ON      s.id = t.id
```

In both systems, you could use inline sets:

```
SELECT  CASE s.id WHEN t.id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM    (
        SELECT  1 AS id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 AS id
        UNION ALL
        …
        ) t
LEFT JOIN
        sometable s
ON      s.id = t.id
```

Comment: SQL Server specific. He also needs a MySql solution.

Comment: I cannot path in the query somehow my list ?

Comment: @Night Walker - you want to use an external file as the list of IDs?  You need to tell us that!

Comment: @NightWalker: in `MySQL`, no. In `SQL Server 2008`, you can fill a table variable on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

strike that (my) answer.

When you say "path in" do you mean "pass in" or point to a file in the external file system?